# Haskell mod malfunction?

Tags: haskell, modulo

Here is my Haskell function to remove `2::Int` and `5::Int` from a list:

```
remPrimesFactors25 :: [Int] -> [Int]
remPrimesFactors25 [] = []
remPrimesFactors25 (x:xs)
  | x == 2                  = remPrimesFactors25 xs
  | x == 5                  = remPrimesFactors25 xs
  | otherwise           = x : remPrimesFactors25 xs
```

```
λ>  remPrimesFactors25 [2,5,23]
[23]
λ>  remPrimesFactors25 [2,5,23] == [23]
True
λ>  product (remPrimesFactors25 [2,5,23])
23
λ>  product [23]
23
λ>  product (remPrimesFactors25 [2,5,23]) == product [23]
True
```

**Here's my problem.** Why does this happen?

```
λ>  mod (10^22) (product (remPrimesFactors25 [2,5,23]) )
15
λ>  mod (10^22) (product [23])
1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question?

Comment: `remPrimesFactors` returns an `Int`, not an `Integer`, so that forces `10^22` to be treated as an `Int` as well, resulting in overflow.

Answer (score 2):

`remPrimesFactors` always returns a list of `Int` values, not `Integer` values. Since `mod` requires both arguments to have the same type, `10^22` is *also* treated as an `Int`, which doesn't have the precision to handle the large number accurately.

```
Prelude> 10^22 :: Integer
10000000000000000000000
Prelude> 10^22 :: Int
1864712049423024128
```

Comment: ...with the underlying issue being that `Int` is only guaranteed to go up to ~`2^29` (and GHC gives you something like `2^63` on 64-bit systems), which are neither enough to hold `10^22 > 2^(3*22) = 2^66`.

Comment: You might want to mention that `fromIntegral` can be used to fix the code.

Answer (score 2):

You are working with an `Int`. An [**`Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Int) uses a fixed number of bits, and can represent at least all values in the range of -2<sup>29</sup> to 2<sup>29</sup>-1. Typically on 32-bit machine it will take the range of -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, and on a 64-bit machine -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup>-1. `10^22` however is greater than these ranges. This means that `10^22` for an `Int` will be represented on a 64-bit machine for example as 1'864'712'049'423'024'128.

If you use an `Integer`, which can represent values of arbitrary size, then there is no such problem. If you thus rewrite the function to:

```
remPrimesFactors25 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
remPrimesFactors25 = filter (\x -> x != 2 && x != 5)
```

then `10^22` will be interpreted as an `Integer`, and thus `10^22` will take as value 10'000'000'000'000'000'000'000.

You however do not need to calculate `10^22`. You can use algorithms like [**`powerMod :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.11.0.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Modular.html#v:powMod)  of the [**`arithmoi`** package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi/).